# Laravel Job isn't affected by DB data change.. really?

Tags: laravel, caching, queue, laravel-9

I have Laravel application that retrievies data from external services via API using queued jobs. Jobs can be started both by user or by schedule.

I use standart queue:work supervised by supervisor for this. Queue driver is database.

I store API settings in DB and read them from DB each time loading process is started (in other words - each time new job is started).

But when user changes theese settings (and controller updated data via $myModelObject->save() ) I can see that job still uses old outdated settings until it's restarted (manually or according to queue settings). Despite the fact that it reads data from DB after changes were made by user.

Seems like it uses some cached data and that cache doesnt react on data update made from outside of job)

So the **question** is - how to force job read data (al or just some critical) from DB without using cache?

I know that I can:

- use queue:listen instead
- use queue:work --stop-when-empty  that is pretty the same as previous

In my case I've solved the probem using "listen" because I dont have too many jobs to care about memory using so much. But if I had?

Thanx in advance for any clue.

Comment: Please, do share code where this is happening, and share the contructor of the Job. I am 99% sure the job is not retreiving data from the Model. The model is serialized and should be re getting all the stuff, but if it is not, instead of passing a model, just store the ID and manually do a `find` on the job handle (just to try out if this solves the issue, in that case we would know that the Job is no re getting the data but using the already serialized data)

Comment: Job does not "cache" database data at all but you are probably sending serialized data to the job that is not updated. As matias states include the code and it can be fixed.

Comment: Thanx guys! you were right, it was by bad. Each time Job is run, it's "handle" method instantiates new ApiDataProvider class that loads settings from DB in constructor, BUT I totally forgot that I'd made ApiDataProvider a singleton for optimization purposes. So I've been caching it myself all this time. Thanx for the clue :)